# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'upper' in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

My code:

Loop Delete Project

```
 ${fruits}  create list     ['16825', '11209', '16902']
    :FOR    ${project_element}  IN    ${fruits}
     \    Log    Get Text    ${project_element}
```

When i run test suite then the error appear: 
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mysl.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the FOR loop to work properly you need to use `@` before the variable name after `IN`:

```
:FOR    ${project_element}  IN    @{fruits}
```

Also, the use of `:` and `\` are being deprecated. The correct format for a FOR loop is now:

```
FOR  ${project_element}  IN  @{fruits}
    Log  Get Text  ${project_element}
END
```

For more information see [For loops](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops) in the robot framework user guide.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your `Create List` as it is, rather change to:
`${fruits}=     create list         16825    11209    16902`

Also, you cannot 'chain' keywords together in `Log     Get Text    ${project_element}`, you must use a variable in between, e.g.:

```
${text}=    Get Text  ${project_element}
Log  ${text}
```

As a whole the working solution would be close to:

```
${fruits}=     create list         16825    11209    16902
FOR    ${project_element}  IN    @{fruits}
    ${text}=    Get Text  ${project_element}
    Log  ${text}
END
```